# Android how to print a array in text view or anything

Tags: android, arrays, printing, for-loop, textarea

I have a array of words and I would like to print the array of words onto the screen in a text view after a button is clicked. i was using a for loop to go through the whole list and then set text, but i keep getting a error with that plus it will just replace the last value, so it wont print the whole array. If anybody could explain to me how to do like a g.drawSting() but android version that would be great. my code rt now is not with me but it something like:
-I'm a beginner to android btw, probably could tell by this question tho.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//code for a button just being pressed{
 //goes to two methods to fix the private array{
     for(int y=0; y<=array.size()-1; y++){
        textArea.setText(aarray.get(y));   //prints all strings in the array
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int arraySize = myArray.size();
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
myTextView.append(myArray[i]);
}
```

if you want to print one by one, then use \n

```
myTextView.append(myArray[i]);
myTextView.append("\n");
```

**PS:** 
Whoever suggesting to change .size() to .length(), thanks for you suggestion.

FYI,
The questioner mentioned the variable name is `array.size()`  in question, so the answer also having the same variable name, to make it easier for the questioner.

if your variable (myArray) is an `Array` use `myArray.length()`, if it is `ArrayList` use `myArray.size()`

Comment: This answer could be wrong because arrays have `.length` property in java and they do not have `.size()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine all text into a String before you can give it the TextView. Otherwise you overwrite the text all the time.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     int size = array.size();
     boolean appendSeparator = false;
     for(int y=0; y < size; y++){

        if (appendSeparator)
            sb.append(','); // a comma
        appendSeparator = true;

        sb.append(array.get(y));
     }
     textArea.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: `y<array.size()` would read better, and a for each loop (although we don't know the type of the array here) would look even better.

Comment: it's even better to get the `.size()` call out of the `for` loop so it does not need to evaluate the size each time the loop runs.

Comment: size is just a getter on a field so that would not make a significant difference (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438710/using-collection-size-in-for-loop-comparision)

Comment: That depends on the implementation of `List`. If it's just an `ArrayList` yes no real difference (although locally caching the size is still faster) But unless you know the implementation details of a class then I'd prefer it that way - unless you are multithreaded and have to assume that `list.size()` might change.

Answer (score 0):

I use this no-index solution, just an easy to remember one liner:

`for(File file:list) Log.d(TAG, "list: " + file.getPath());`